# What is the best way to store a 16 × (2^20) matrix in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix, file-io, bigdata

I am thinking of writing the data to a file. Does anyone have an example of how to write a big amount of data to a file?

**Edit:** Most elements in the matrix are zeroes, others are `uint32`. I guess the simplest `save()` and `load()` would work, as @Jonas suggested.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess nobody's seen the edit about the zeroes :)

If they're mostly zeroes, you should convert your matrix to its sparse representation and **then** save it. You can do that with the [sparse](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/sparse.html) function.

#### Code

```
z = zeros(10000,10000);
z(123,456) = 1;
whos z
z = sparse(z);
whos z
```

#### Output

```
Name          Size                   Bytes  Class     Attributes

  z         10000x10000            800000000  double  

Name          Size               Bytes  Class     Attributes

  z         10000x10000            40016  double    sparse
```

I don't think the sparse implementation is designed to handle `uint32`.

Comment: Correct on sparse an uint32, but, double should have an acceptable range.

Comment: Right, I was trying to emphasize that the original data being `uint32` is not going to help.

Answer (score 3):

If you're concerned with keeping the size of the data file as small as possible, here are some suggestions:

- Write the data to a binary file (i.e. using [FWRITE](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/fwrite.html)) instead of to a text file (i.e. using [FPRINTF](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/fprintf.html)).
- If your data contains all integer values, convert it to or save it as a [signed or unsigned integer type](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f2-12135.html#f2-52790) instead of the default [double precision type](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f2-12135.html#f2-101310) MATLAB uses.
- If your data contains floating point values, but you don't need the range or resolution of the default [double precision type](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f2-12135.html#f2-101310), convert it to or save it as a [single precision type](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f2-12135.html#f2-108458).
- If your data is sufficiently sparse (i.e. there are many more zeroes than non-zeroes in your matrix), then you can use the [FIND](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/find.html) function to get the row and column indices of the non-zero values, then just save these to your file.

Here are a couple of examples to illustrate:

```
data = double(rand(16,2^20) <= 0.00001);  %# A large but very sparse matrix

%# Writing the values as type double:
fid = fopen('data_double.dat','w');  %# Open the file
fwrite(fid,size(data),'uint32');     %# Write the matrix size (2 values)
fwrite(fid,data,'double');           %# Write the data as type double
fclose(fid);                         %# Close the file

%# Writing the values as type uint8:
fid = fopen('data_uint8.dat','w');  %# Open the file
fwrite(fid,size(data),'uint32');    %# Write the matrix size (2 values)
fwrite(fid,data,'uint8');           %# Write the data as type uint8
fclose(fid);                        %# Close the file

%# Writing out only the non-zero values:
[rowIndex,columnIndex,values] = find(data);  %# Get the row and column indices
                                             %#   and the non-zero values
fid = fopen('data_sparse.dat','w');  %# Open the file
fwrite(fid,numel(values),'uint32');  %# Write the length of the vectors (1 value)
fwrite(fid,rowIndex,'uint32');       %# Write the row indices
fwrite(fid,columnIndex,'uint32');    %# Write the column indices
fwrite(fid,values,'uint8');          %# Write the non-zero values
fclose(fid);                         %# Close the file
```

The files created above will differ drastically in size. The file `'data_double.dat'` will be about 131,073 KB, `'data_uint8.dat'` will be about 16,385 KB, and `'data_sparse.dat'` will be less than 2 KB.

Note that I also wrote the data\vector sizes to the files so that the data can be read back in (using [FREAD](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/fread.html)) and reshaped properly. Note also that if I did not supply a `'double'` or `'uint8'` argument to [FWRITE](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/fwrite.html), MATLAB would be smart enough to figure out that it didn't need to use the default double precision and would only use 8 bits to write out the data values (since they are all 0 and 1).

Answer (score 2):

How is the data generated? How do you need to access the data?

If I calculate correctly, the variable is less than 200MB if it's all double. Thus, you can easily save and load it as a single .mat file if you need to access it from Matlab only.

```
%# create data
data = zeros(16,2^20);

%# save data
save('myFile.mat','data');

%# clear data to test everything works
clear data

%# load data
load('myFile.mat')
```